# Display row from a table if a condition in another table is met

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have two tables, `students` and `applications`. A student has an ID and a name, and can make many applications. The applications table has an ID, the student ID as a FK, and an APPLICATION_STATUS.

I want to display all students where **none** of their applications have 'APPLICANT ACCEPTED OFFER' in APPLICATION_STATUS.

I've tried:

```
SELECT STUDENTS.FIRST_NAME ||' '||STUDENTS.LAST_NAME "Student Name"
FROM STUDENTS
JOIN APPLICATIONS ON STUDENTS.SRN = APPLICATIONS.SRN
WHERE APPLICATION_STATUS != 'APPLICANT ACCEPTED OFFER';
```

This is what I've tried so far, but instead of displaying the students that haven't accepted an offer, it is showing **all** applications that were not accepted.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and an expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a join, use `not exists`

```
 SELECT STUDENTS.FIRST_NAME ||' '||STUDENTS.LAST_NAME "Student Name"
 FROM STUDENTS
 WHERE not exists ( select 1 from 
    APPLICATIONS where STUDENTS.SRN = APPLICATIONS.SRN
    And APPLICATION_STATUS = 'APPLICANT ACCEPTED OFFER');
```